# Infinite for loop with 2d array

Tags: c, file-io, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I'm having a problem fixing this infinite loop.
I've done some tests so I'm pretty sure the loop isn't  when reading the file.
Right after "printReportHeading();" is a for loop. I am pretty sure that is what is causing the issues.
How would I go about fixing this.
Is it something to do with initialization of the 2 dimensional array?

Code:

```
  int main(void)
   {
    FILE* fileIn;
    FILE* printFile;

    float average;

    char letterGrade;

    int wholeArray [MAX_STUDENTS][MAX_PROFILE],
            letterFreq[5];

   printInstructions();

    fileIn = fopen("input11.dat", "r");

    if(fileIn == NULL)
    {
            printf("\n\nFILE COULD NOT BE LOCATED\n\n");
    }
    else
    {
            printFile = fopen("upchurch.txt", "w");

            loadData(fileIn, wholeArray);

            printReportHeading();

            for(int row = 0; row < MAX_STUDENTS; row++)
            {
                    average = calcAverage(wholeArray);
                    letterGrade = determineLetter(average);
                    printLine(printFile, wholeArray, average, letterGrade);

                    switch(letterGrade)
                    {
                            case 'A':
                                    letterFreq[0]++;
                                    break;
                            case 'B':
                                    letterFreq[1]++;
                                    break;
                            case 'C':
                                    letterFreq[2]++;
                                    break;
                            case 'D':
                                    letterFreq[3]++;
                                    break;
                            default:
                                    letterFreq[4]++;
                                    break;
                    }
            }

            printHighScores(printFile, wholeArray);
            printLowScores(printFile, wholeArray);
            printAverageScores(printFile, wholeArray);
            fprintf(printFile, "---------------------------------------------\n");

            printHistogram(printFile, letterFreq);
    }

    return;
}


/******************************************************************************
 *Prints the instructions to the user*
******************************************************************************/
void printInstructions(void)
 {
    printf("=================================================================\n");
    printf("= This program takes up to 40 student's ID and five quiz grades =\n");
    printf("= then finds each students letter grade, average of each quiz,  =\n");
    printf("= highest and lowest grade of each quiz, and creates a          =\n");
    printf("= histogram of all of the students letter gradesa as a whole.   =\n");
    printf("=================================================================\n\n");

    return;
}
/******************************************************************************
 *Gets the data from the file for the user*
******************************************************************************/
int loadData(FILE* fileIn, int wholeArray[][MAX_PROFILE])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_STUDENTS; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < MAX_PROFILE; j++)
            {
                    fscanf(fileIn, "%d", &wholeArray[i][j]);
            }

    return 0;
}
/******************************************************************************
 *Prints the report heading*
******************************************************************************/
void printReportHeading()
{
    printf("Student   Quiz 1   Quiz 2   Quiz 3   Quiz 4   Quiz 5   Average   Letter\n");

    return;
 }

/******************************************************************************
 *Calculates each student's average and letter grade*
******************************************************************************/
float calcAverage (int wholeArray[][MAX_PROFILE])
{
    int totalGrades = 0;

  for (int i = 1; i < MAX_PROFILE; i++)
  {
     totalGrades += *wholeArray[i];
  }


     return (totalGrades / 5.0f);
}
/******************************************************************************
 *Finds the letter grade*
******************************************************************************/
char determineLetter(float average)
{
    char letterGrade;

    if (average >= 90)
            letterGrade = 'A';
    else if (average >= 80)
            letterGrade = 'B';
    else if (average >= 70)
            letterGrade = 'C';
    else if (average >= 60)
            letterGrade = 'D';
    else
            letterGrade = 'F';

    return letterGrade;
}
/******************************************************************************
 Prints a line of students information
******************************************************************************/
void printLine(FILE* printFile, int wholeArray[][MAX_PROFILE], float average, char letterGrade)
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= MAX_STUDENTS; i++)
       for(int j = 0; j < MAX_PROFILE; j++)
       {
          fprintf(printFile, "%d", wholeArray[i][j]);
             if ((j = MAX_PROFILE))
             {
                printf("%3.2f", average);
                printf("%c", letterGrade);
                j = 0;
             }
       }
    fprintf(printFile, "---------------------------------------------------\n");

    return;
}

/******************************************************************************
 Find the high score of each quiz
******************************************************************************/
void printHighScores(FILE* printFile, int wholeArray[][MAX_PROFILE])
{
    int highestTest = 0;

    fprintf(printFile, "High ");

    for (int i = 1; i < MAX_PROFILE; i++)
    {
            for(int j = 0; j < MAX_STUDENTS; j++)
            {
                    if (highestTest < wholeArray[j][i])
                    {
                            highestTest = wholeArray[j][i];
                    }
            }

            fprintf(printFile, "%3d", highestTest);
    }
    return;
}

/******************************************************************************
 Finds the low score of each quiz
******************************************************************************/
void printLowScores(FILE* printFile, int wholeArray[][MAX_PROFILE])
{
    int lowestTest = 100;

    fprintf(printFile, "Low  ");

    for (int i = 1; i < MAX_PROFILE; i++)
    {
            for(int j = 0; j < MAX_STUDENTS; j++)
            {
                    if (lowestTest > wholeArray[j][i])
                    {
                            lowestTest = wholeArray[j][i];
                    }
            }

            fprintf(printFile, "%3d", lowestTest);
    }
    return;
} 

/******************************************************************************
 Finds the average score of each quiz
******************************************************************************/
void printAverageScores(FILE* printFile, int wholeArray[][MAX_PROFILE])
{
    float averageTest = 0.0;

    int i;

    fprintf(printFile, "Average   ");

    for (i = 1; i < MAX_PROFILE; i++)
    {
            for(int j = 0; j < MAX_STUDENTS; j++)
            {
                    averageTest += wholeArray[j][i];

            }
            averageTest = averageTest / i;

            fprintf(printFile, "%5.2f", averageTest);
    }
    return;
}

 /******************************************************************************
 Prints histogram of letter frequency
 ******************************************************************************/
void printHistogram(FILE* printFile, int letterFreq[5])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
            for (int j = 1; j <= letterFreq[i]; j++)
                    printf("*");
            printf("\n");
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: If the problem is an infinite loop (rather than say a crash caused by `printFile` being NULL), the loop must be in code you're not showing us.  Can you edit your question to include code for `loadData`, `calcAverage`, `determineLetter` and `printLine` please?

Comment: I added the rest of the code, thanks for showing interest @simonc

Comment: Unless MAX_STUDENTS is changing value or a number unreachable by `int row`, there's no way the problem is in your main loop. Please show your other functions, and how `MAX_STUDENTS` is defined. Be sure to step through you code with a debugger, an infinite loop should be easy to find with one.

Comment: @hmjd Sorry! MAX_STUDENTS 40 MAX_PROFILE 6

Comment: Can't you pause the program when it is running in the debugger and it seems to be in an infinite loop, to see at which line it is?

Answer (score 1):

In `printLine`, you have:

```
if ((j = MAX_PROFILE))
{
    …
    j = 0;
}
```

There are two things wrong with this. First, `j = MAX_PROFILE` is an assignment, not a comparison. It sets `j` to `MAX_PROFILE` and evaluates to true, causing the body of the `if` to be executed.

Then the body of the `if` sets `j` to zero. This causes the inner loop to repeat indefinitely.

I suspect what you intend here is to print the average and the grade after printing all the lines of the student’s profile. In that case, simply print them after the loop on `j`, still inside the loop on `i`. There is no need for a test and no need to set `j` to zero.

Comment: Ok infinite loop is gone now, but I keep getting a bunch of gibberish when I run the code.

Comment: @JesUppy: You should test and debug individual parts of your program. Ensure that each routine does what you want before you call it from other routines.

Comment: Ya, sadly I didn't do that and everything is a jumbled mess...good advice though. I'll try that next time for sure

Comment: @JesUppy: You can still do it this time. Simply test and debug each function in turn.

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't the cause of your bug but `letterFreq` is never initialised so `printHistogram` invokes undefined behaviour and could end up printing billions of "*"s.  The fix for this is simply to initialise the array members to 0

```
letterFreq[5] = {0};
```